# Initializing object with data from postgres run significantly slower than sqlite

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, vector, sqlalchemy

this code first used to query ingredients as a binary vector from database and saved it into an object called Recipe for each of vector

```
...
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        recipes = list(
            select(r for r in RECIPE_INGREDIENT_VECTOR if r.valid == 1))
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(f"Time taken to query recipe vectors: {elapsed_time} seconds")
        start_time = time.time()
        for r in recipes:
            ingredient_vector_int = [int(s)
                                     for s in r.ingredient_vector.split(',')]
            get_recipe_name(r.recipe_id)
            get_ingredients_by_recipe_id(r.recipe_id)
            recipe_obj = Recipe(
                r.recipe_id, get_recipe_name(r.recipe_id),get_ingredients_by_recipe_id(r.recipe_id))
...
```

i have tried to benchmark both of these ORM  :

```
        for r in recipes:
            ingredient_vector_int = [int(s) for s in r.ingredient_vector.split(',')]
            get_recipe_name(r.recipe_id)
            get_ingredients_by_recipe_id(r.recipe_id)
```

```
@db_session
def get_recipe_name(recipe_id):
    p = RAW_RECIPES[recipe_id]
    return p.name

@db_session
def get_ingredients_by_recipe_id(recipe_id):
    recipe_ingredients_str = select(
        r.ingredients for r in RAW_RECIPES if r.id == recipe_id).first().strip("[]")
    result = [s for s in recipe_ingredients_str.split(',')]
    return result
```

comparing between postgres and sqlite , given table raw_recipes in both db has an id column which is indexed  and a primary key
sqlite return the result after 4 seconds and postgres is 7 seconds sometimes worse than that.
If we put both ORM functions inside an object `Recipe` initialization, the result of Sqlite is only about a minute but postgres takes 3-4 times longer than that
I have tried to change ORM for postgres to sqlalchemy and compare with sqlite with pony orm but the problem still persis
any thoughts ? or suggestions ?

Comment: 4 seconds is much too slow. Probably you need to reduce the number of database requests, perhaps by using a join. Is the network latency to the two databases different?

Comment: but the postgres query is much more slower than 4 seconds of sqlite which i still don't know why ? i think network latency might not be a problem because both are running on the same network. One thing to notice is postgres is running on docker container while sqlite sits on the src directory, but i don't think that cause any network problem
the result from postgres is always slower than sqlite each time i run that script @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: If it is a single SQL statement that's taking all the time, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT ...` and add the SQL statement and the result you get to the question. Then we can tell what's going on.